# Powershell - unable to use Python - Error in Path?

Tags: python, powershell

I am not able to use Python in my Powershell. I added Python to my Path, but it does not work as expected.

```
PS C:\Users\xcg5847> $env:Path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Programme\nodejs\;C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\Program Files (x86)\Plantronics\Spokes3G SDK\;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\xcg5847\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\SimonHarrer\mob;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\OpenShift;C:\Users\xcg5847\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts;c:\users\xcg5847\.local\bin;C:\Users\xcg5847\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39;C:\Program Files\Python39
```

By adding:

```
C:\Users\xcg5847\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts
C:\Users\xcg5847\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39
```

I expected it to work.

```
python --version
```

does not through an error, but just does not do anything.

Strangely this even works with pip.

```
pip --version
pip 20.2.3 from c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you just added it as a system environment variable, you might just need to start a new console instance for it to be picked up.

Comment: not that´s not the issue, i restarted the console, even the computer. Maybe it has to do something to do with our IT service >_<

Comment: Run `Get-Command python -All`. The first result is the executable that will be called when you invoke `python` (without a path). Perhaps an unexpected executable by that name happens to come first in your `$env:PATH`.

Comment: You do have `C:\Program Files\Python39` already. Python.exe is not in there ? If so, maybe adding `C:\Users\xcg5847\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39` create a conflict because now you have 2 python.exe in the path (or not... I am not sure of the behavior in this case, it might just be picking the first one)

Comment: In the meantime, you can always use Python by invoking it with the full path. To shorten this, you can always do `
$Python = "C:\Users\xcg5847\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\python.exe"` Then `&$Python --version`` and other commands like this. In fact, even if you don't use it as a final solution, you can 1. test thati t work that way and 2. check if you have another python in `C:\Program Files\Python39` and try the variable with that path to see if that work too. If you indeed have another exe there and it doesn't produce result... then it might be the issue since it is first in your path.